# How to set scale and units equal to 1?

Tags: transforms

I have an object that i can't seem to set as a unit size of 1 with scale of 1.

[image]

For my own sanity, how do you set the scale so that a scale of 1 is also equal to the dimension of 1 unit?

Its super annoying that a scale 1 equals a dimension of 2 for the default cube, it makes no sense.

Comment: From where you are you can just apply the scale and you will have a scale of 1 with the same dimensions

Comment: No if i set it to scale 1 it becomes dimensions of 2.

Comment: I said **apply the scale**, **not change the scale**. You go CTRL + A and choose scale. Just like @Chris said.

Comment: Ah okay, kind've weird blender wouldn't default to 1:1 to start with.

Comment: I think there is something you don't understand about scale. Scale doesn't represent the size of the object. If you have a house of 5 meters high, it means that in Blender this house will be 5 meters high at a scale of 1. At a scale of two, it's going to be 10 meters high and so on.. The default cube is a cube 2mx2mx2m so at a scale of 1 it has a 2m dimensions, that just makes sense. Scale in Blender is like the scale of a Map. If you have a map at 1:1 scale, it doesn't mean all the objects are 1 meters wide, it means all the objects are represented at their original dimensions.

Comment: As @mqbakamqbaka already explained, scale 1 means original size, no matter what that might be in meters/units or whatever. And if you are wondering why this is a dimension of 2 on those mesh primitives and other default objects, that's because they all have **'radius' of 1**, which results in a diameter of 2. Okay, of course it's not the radius when you have a square or cube (it's the radius of the incircle of the square), but it's mathematically based on a unit circle with a radius of 1, so that sin(90°) = 1, cos(0°) = 1 and the circumference is 2π etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL-A -> Scale, then you have 1.

[image]

Comment: Will this then be the default for all future blender projects or just this one project?

Comment: oh sorry, this is just for the selected object. It won't change anything else

Comment: Ah okay thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I don't know why you would need this to be scale 1 = dimensions 1, but technically when you change your default cube like this with ctrl+A you can then go and save this current default cube as your default Blender file and then it always will be like this

Comment: @MikoCG If he's only bothered by the cube at startup this might help, but it won't change the default size of other mesh primitives. Or if he accidentally deletes the cube and wants to add it again ;)